# Actualizar Idiomas registrados en angular-translate

Tags: html, angularjs, traducción

Estoy utilizando el angular-translate y en la configuración de mi aplicación tengo lo siguiente:

```js
corporativas.config(['$translateProvider', 
function ($translateProvider) { 
  //TRANSLATION SYSTEM
  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'locales/locale-',
    suffix: '.json'
  });

  $translateProvider.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'es']);
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en'); //manual decision of translation provider
  $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
  $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
  $translateProvider.useCookieStorage(); //use cookie storage to save the language of the user, updated everytime it changes

}]);
```

Pero los idiomas que están definidos en la función registerAvailableLanguageKeys() són estáticos, pero para mi aplicación estos valores los debo obtener desde la base de datos.

Tengo entendido que en el config de angular no puedo hacer llamadas asíncronas porque el ciclo de vida de angular ejecuta primero el config y puede que en el tiempo de ejecución no me devuelva nada.

Así que me preguntaba si alguien sabe como actualizar los valores del registerAvailableLanguageKeys() desde un controller o desde el run.

ANEXO:
Utilizo angularjs versión 1.6.4
y angular-translate 2.15.1

Comment: Quizás esta página te ayude. Explica como cargar nuevos idiomas de manera asincrona. [Asynchronous Loading](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading)

Comment: Hola Noely, tengo el mismo problema, necesito transformar la información que me llega de base de datos pintada con mi NGFOR

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion, utiliza el metodo [`$traslate.use`](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate):

> Indica a angular-translate que idioma usar con la tecla de idioma dada.
>   Este método se usa para **cambiar el idioma en tiempo de ejecución**.
>   También se encarga de guardar la clave de idioma en una tienda
>   configurada para que su aplicación recuerde el idioma elegido.

Aqui un ejemplo de como al dar clic se cambia el idioma de ingles a espanol:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    TITLE: 'Hello',
    FOO: 'This is a paragraph.',
    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'Inglish',
    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'Spanish'
  });
  $translateProvider.translations('es', {
    TITLE: 'Hola',
    FOO: 'Esto es un parafo.',
    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'Ingles',
    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'Espanol'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
  
   // cambias el idioma utilizando el metodo $translate.use
    $translate.use(key);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.6.1/angular-translate.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

<div class="well">
    <h2 translate="TITLE" >Hello</h2>
    <p translate="FOO">This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
                <button ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_EN">english</button>
                <button ng-click="changeLanguage('es')" translate="BUTTON_LANG_DE">german</button>
              </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero lo que quiero es modificar los idiomas disponibles en registerAvailableLanguageKeys porque los que están puestos en mi código son estáticos, pero deben ser dinámicos (bbdd).